# Font-weight not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

Im building a responsive website. Using a w3schools demo as a template to start with. Ive been having trouble with the fonts tho. Im trying to get the h1 to be Roboto Bold. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08ggqgom/

```
#welcome{
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
```

If anyone could help with the font and also maybe cleaning it up a bit like separating the css and html that would be greatly appreciated as i keep breaking something when i try. ( or cleaning up all the class ids from w3schools)

Answer (score 2):

You have assign welcome as a an id with `#` when in your HTML file you will add welcome in a class. So in the css file try this:

```
.welcome {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now run code snippet, Your needed font added into your document, bold font is working. Remove "body{background-color:gray}" from my code, I have added dark background to show white text/content in document.

```css
body{background-color:gray}
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .welcome{
     font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
     font-weight: 700;
    }
    h1{
     font-size:30px !important;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>W3.CSS Template</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

    body, html {height: 100%}
    .bgimg {
        background-image: url('images/bg.png');
        min-height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-white">
      <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding-large w3-xlarge">
        Logo
      </div>
      <div class="w3-display-middle">
        <h1 class="welcome">Welcome to Launchpad</h1>
        <hr class="w3-border-grey" style="margin:auto;width:40%">
        <p class="w3-large w3-center">35 days left</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-padding-large">
        Powered by <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp" target="_blank">w3.css</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Warren Breedlove, please accept answer, if I have fixed your font issue. If you did not get bold font, please comment your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your css you are triggering the id `#welcome` but you have to write it as a class `.welcome` and everything works fine :)

So it looks like that

```
.welcome {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
```